# Center buttons in table row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table with two or one buttons.
I would like to center the title of the td tag, center the two buttons in one line with some space between them, and in case there is no button to avoid the gridline coming up (maybe somehow fixed the row height?) Note that my code is through PHP code. if something exists echo the buttons.

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
         <th>Booking #</th>
         <th>Vehicle #</th>
         <th>Pickup Date</th>
         <th>Drop Date</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Options</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td class='text-center d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex'>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-success btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Approve</span></a>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-dark btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Cancel</span></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td class='text-center d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex'>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-dark btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Cancel</span></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td class='text-center d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex'>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-success btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Approve</span></a>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-dark btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Cancel</span></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td class='text-center d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex'>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `d-md-flex` from `td`
2. Add a `div` into your `td`
3. Add classes `d-flex` and `justify-content-evenly` to your new div
4. Add class `text-center` to your th

Something like that :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
         <th>Booking #</th>
         <th>Vehicle #</th>
         <th>Pickup Date</th>
         <th>Drop Date</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th class="text-center">Options</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-success btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Approve</span></a>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-dark btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Cancel</span></a>
             </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-dark btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Cancel</span></a>
           </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-success btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Approve</span></a>
            <a href='#CancelBookingDialog' data-book-id='".$BookingID."' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#CancelBookingDialog' class='btn btn-dark btn-icon-split open-CancelBookingDialog'>
            <span class='text'>Cancel</span></a>
           </div>
             </td>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>Lorem</td>
         <td>
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
           </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want a different display for your two buttons, you can use the flex option [justify content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content).